# Robot framework and DRY: function steps repeat testcase steps

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, robotframework

I want to automate two testcases:
1) Log in to system

```
Valid Login  
    Given browser is opened to login page  
    When user "demo" logs in with password "mode"  
    Then welcome page should be open
```

2) Do anything after logging in

```
Change first name
    [Setup]    Log in 
    Given user is on account page
    When user edits first-name field
    Then new first name is displayed in first-name field

*** Keywords ***
Log in
   Open browser to login page
   Log in with username "demo" and password "mode"
   Verify that welcome page is opened
```

For the second one I have to write a keyword that fully repeats steps of the first testcase.

This happens a lot in testsuits, so I end up with a lot of steps repeated twice in my project. Is there a neat trick to avoid such code duplication, while keeping top-level testcases look like Gherkin?

Are there best-practices for this issue?

Comment: Update the question with your code trials and relevant HTML please

Comment: Have you considered moving all of the repeated steps into a keyword? And/or, have you read the user guide where it talks about data driven tests?

Comment: If not already, you should use a page object pattern (POM). Note that DRY is not necessary a good thing especially if removing the duplicated code makes it harder to understand what is going on or introduces some logic.

Comment: Florent, I guess you just gave me the answer: if DRY is against readability, prefer readability. I just though I was missing some technique to have them both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the Gherkin-style login steps to a keyword and wrote the `Valid Login` Test Case that does nothing.

Letting `Test Setup` call it for you or writing it explicitly in the test is a matter of preference I guess.

A good resource: [How to write good test cases using Robot Framework](https://github.com/robotframework/HowToWriteGoodTestCases/blob/master/HowToWriteGoodTestCases.rst)

```
*** Settings ***
Test Setup            Log in

*** Test Cases ***

Valid Login
    No Operation

Change first name
    Given user is on account page
    When user edits first-name field
    Then new first name is displayed in first-name field

*** Keywords ***

Log in
    Given browser is opened to login page
    When user "demo" logs in with password "mode"  
    Then welcome page should be open
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Eddy. The idea was not in keeping Gherking, it was in making "Test Cases" section serve as documentation AND avoid code repetition at the same time. As I understand, latter is not possible at all.